# Correct way to model structure

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this model:http://pastebin.com/W5n6rRiJ

If I put the schema "Cliente" on top, I have a patch error.

So I put it down the other models, but with this I can't do operations in the schema "Cliente". 
For example, if I post or get a "cliente" the only thing going for the database is: "_id": "57d2ebeb732b1d4c1973906d", "__v": 0"

I'm following the book mongoose for application development, but stopped it.

Thanks

Comment: Where Usuario is declared and why Cliente is capitalize letter and other not?

Comment: Ohh sorry, user is in another model: http://pastebin.com/EzCMndah

Comment: I think I fixed it that way: http://pastebin.com/dvQfw4VG